# How can I change the tick values for a log-scale plot generated with the plotly package in R?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Here is a reproducible example of what I'm referring to :

```
library(plotly)
s<-seq(1,8)
p<-plot_ly(x=~s) %>%
add_trace(y=~exp(s),name="exponential") %>%
add_trace(y=~s,name="linear") %>%
layout(yaxis=list(type="log"))
# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials : https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link=api_create(p,filename="axes-6")
chart_link
```

[image]

In theory, what I'm trying to do is quite simple, but I can't for the life of me find an example of someone having done it. All I want to do is alter the way that the y-axis ticks are labeled. Instead of going to 10 and then using implied zeros between 10 and 100, 100 and 1000, I would like to keep the zeros there for ease of interpretation. The current presentation is confusing for some, and I'd like to clear that up.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've been adding

```
tickformat = ".1r"
```

to the axis, and it works. However, if you use have big numbers, it doesn't look good.

Comment: This worked for me too in python, I used:
`fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat = "0.1r")`

Answer (score 0):

For y-range wide enough you can use:

```
tickformat: "f"
```

Unfortunately for short range you will get duplicated values: `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...`

The only working solution is to set `tickvals`: `[0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50...]` or generate them in a `do-while` loop.

Tried to use [GitHub d3-format/ReadMe: locale.format(specifier)](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format) but with no success.